# Queries in Content Provider

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

Is it possible to use advanced SQL queries involving inner join/outer Join in Content Providers? How is this done? My other question: Is it necessary to create a new Database inside Content Providers? Can we use an already existing DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do an inner join/outer join in a content provider.
Like this:

```
String tables = "table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON (table1.sportId = table2._id)";
queryBuilder.setTables(tables);
```

And don't need to make a new instance you can just pass it through in the constructor if you want. Or make from you database class an Singleton.